# SharePoint page scrolls to top when I enter something in people picker

Tags: sharepoint-server, people-picker

I have a list edit form open in the modal dialog, there are multiple people picker fields, whenever I enter something in any of the people picker control page scrolls to top(within modal dialog).
Please help me on this.

Thanks